# Asynchronous call in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am executing a function and i want to pause execution for some time.

```
function a(){

}

//here some code --- I am using result of a function here...
```

Can anyone help me... how to use asynchronous call??

Comment: you can use setTimeout("",function(),time);

Comment: what part of this is async? and the pause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function should accept a callback parameter that it would execute after doing its thing. So something like:

```
function a(callback) {
    // do something

    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Then you would call it like:

```
a(function () {
    alert("finished");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just using

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // do some work after the timeout pause
}, 1500);
```

It is waiting for 1500 milliseconds before executing the function contained.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean - to use result of a function, assign it to a variable:

```
var r = a();

//....some code...

//using result of a function here

alert("result of a(): " + r);
```

In case of AJAX or something similar use the callback function provided to you, for example with jQuery:

```
$.post("myajaxpage", function() {
    //callback function - executed after request is finished
    var r = a();
    alert("result of a(): " + r);
});
```